# What does INM in COMP2_INM mean?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I intend to use the internal comparators in the STM32F334R8 microcontroller.

[image]

If you look at the picture above, right beside "input[-]" you will see INM. You will also see COMP2_INM at the bottom right part of the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The comparator has two analog inputs, and compares them to generate a signal that can be routed back to a GPIO (in this case COMP2_OUT), as well as to other destinations such as timers, interrupts, etc. The output of the comparator goes high when the INP voltage is greater than the INM voltage - presumably these mean "IN Plus" and "IN Minus".